# setTimeout, clearTimeout in closure

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, actionscript

```
var clearId:int = setTimeout(function():void{
            //some code here
            clearTimeout(clearId);
        },2000);
```

Is this valid AS3? Anyone see problems with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst this compiles without warnings or errors, and is valid AS3, there is un-needed code.

The [setTimeout](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#setTimeout%28%29) function only runs a function once.

The [setInterval](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#setInterval%28%29) function on the other hand runs a function at a specified interval until clearInterval is called.

clearTimeout is used to stop a timeout event that has been set occuring.
Because the timeout only occurs once, there is no need to clear it in the timeout function.
If you were using setInterval, then you would need to clearInterval when you no longer wanted the function to be called.

Comment: Would it be required to call clearTimeout if setTimeout was used with a function instead of a closure like :
    setTimeout(someFunction,2000);

Comment: Ahum... "The setTimeout function only runs a function once."
So no, it wouldn't be required since it only runs once.

Comment: So clearTimeout is only necessary to stop something before it triggers?

Comment: Exactly - clearTimeout is used to stop a timeout before it triggers.

Answer (score 1):

*Is it valid?* Yes. 
*Does it work?* Yes.
*Does it make any sense?* No.

A timeout only executes once.  The closure necessarily is only called after the timeout has already completed.  Now, if you were using an *interval*, it would make sense.

The method works because the compiler defines all of those local variables up front, making them automatically accessible.  Basically, it does something like this:

```
var clearId:int;
clearId = setInterval(function():void
{
    clearInterval(clearId);
}, 2000);
```